# DrawerLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout, collapsing-toolbar-layout

```
Использовал DrawerLayout вместе с CollapsingToolbarLayout и Tablayout .

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".sferaActivity"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/nav_header_bg"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/myToolBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <ru.qwerq.qwerq.MyNestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ru.qwerq.qwerq.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ru.qwerq.qwerq.MyNestedScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Вот что имеем на выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это полоска под status-баром уже не первый раз пытается испортить мне настроение. Что это за явление, откуда это берется? Что нужно подправить чтобы устранить этот баг? Пока не добавился DrawerLayout все было в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`  у `CollapsingToolbarLayout` , 
должно помочь. А вообще этот атрибут нужно ставить только на корневой элемент, а не во всех view
`

Comment: Удалил у всех элементов, кроме корневого. Все в порядке!